# android call recorder for android 8.0 and above

Tags: android, native, phone-call, call-recording

I'm working auto call recorder app, I'm able to record voice call on below 8.0 but from android 8.0 and above for use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` need `system-permission`.

How can I fix this problem and record a phone call?

Comment: Did you find any solution?